# When configuring a site-site VPN in Azure, why can't vpn gateway be configured without local network gateway?

Tags: azure, vpn

According to the documentation, the local network gateway is a representation of on-prem VPN device. Then we set up a connection between the VPN Virtual N/W Gateway and this Local Network gateway.
Why do we need a separate entity like LGN? Why can't the VPN VNG connect directly to on-prem VPN device?

Answer (score 0):

It was just designed this way, probably for better management at scale.  A route based VNG can connect to multiple sites so it's a separate resource per site.  Potentially you could give an engineer access to the VNG and not to the LNG(s) or vice versa if required.  I think they probably could have combined the LNG with the connection resource personally.